# Show hide/div based on drop down value at page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, model-binding

I have the following code that I use to hide/show a `div` using a drop-down. If the Value of the drop-down is 1, I show the `div`, otherwise I hide it.

```
var pattern = jQuery('#pattern');
    var select = pattern.value;
    pattern.change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '1') {
            $('#hours').show();
        }
        else $('hours').hide();
    });
```

The `select` drop down retrieves its value from the database using form model binding:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="pattern" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Pattern <span class="required">*</span></label>
   <div class="col-sm-6">
   {{Form::select('pattern',['0'=> 'Pattern 0','1'=> 'Pattern 1'],null,
   ['id'=>'pattern','class' => 'select-block-level chzn-select'])}}
   </div>
</div>
```

This `select` drop-down then hides or shows the following `div`:

```
<div id="hours" style="border-radius:15px;border: dotted;" >
   <p>Example text</p>
</div>
```

**The problem:**

The div won't be hidden if the pattern stored in the database is set to 0. I have to manually select "Pattern 0" from the drop down to change it. I know that is due to the `.change()` method. But how do I make it hide/show on page load?

Comment: Haven't you tried "pattern.change()" at the end of your JS or at end of your view file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in such case I store the anonymous function reference as below:

```
var checkPattern = function () {
  if ($('#pattern').val() == '1') {
    $('#hours').show();
  }
  else $('#hours').hide();
}
```

It makes the code ready to use in more then one place.
Now your issue could be resolve in a more elegant way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // add event handler
  $('#pattern').on('change', checkPattern);
  // call to adjust div
  checkPattern();
});
```

Comment: This was the solution that worked. I don't know why it was given a down vote.

Comment: There was also one more answer on the page and now it is deleted. A jealous meltdown?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the element "should" be visible by default, you just then have to check condition to "hide it" (you don't have to SHOW an element that is already visible...) :

```
if(pattern.value != %WHATEVER%) { $('#hours').toggle(); }
```

Then, to switch display on event or condition or whatever :

```
pattern.change(function(evt){
    $('#hours').toggle();
});
```

Not sure that your event will work. I'd try something like

```
$(document).on(..., function(evt){
    //behaviour
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/